# How to detect untextured parts in 3D-model

Tags: 3d, texture-mapping, raycasting, hololens

my team and me are currently working on a software for the microsoft hololens. We are using Unity and coding in c#. The goal is to 3D-scan rooms and also texturing them. Afterwards they will be uploaded to our university server and can be downloaded to a VR-PC.
So our problem now is, we dont know how to detect the untextured parts of the room.  Maybe raycasts? The 3D-Mesh is always changing a bit which makes it a bit harder.

Comment: Hi.  "how to detect the untextured parts of the room", can you explain what 'untextured parts' refers to?  If you want to get hold of the 3dmesh that the hololens generates, you can use a [SurfaceObserver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/spatial-mapping#using-the-surface-observer) which will give you access to the 3D scan.  Raycasting is done by the Unity engine on the mesh that the Hololens has given to unity, casting rays won't help you get hold of the hololens's mesh.

Comment: So we are generating uv coordinates to map the photos on the mesh. This part is working fine. The ux is just horrible if you say to the user:"do as much photos as you want". We are looking for a solution to detect where arent photos to map.
Ps: sorry for my bad english skills

Comment: Aah, makes sense, you have users pre-scanning a room and want to be able to detect parts which they haven't scanned yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is a process called "[Spatial Understanding](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/mixed-reality/blob/master/mixed-reality-docs/case-study-expanding-the-spatial-mapping-capabilities-of-hololens.md#the-spatial-understanding-code)" which could be used to detect the progress of an initial room scan.  I am unsure if the docs linked above are super up to date with the current MRTK, or if they refer to an older version, but they could be a good starting point either way.

An example can be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUmTi3_Ynus&feature=youtu.be&t=80).  You could use "Topology Queries" to get the floor, ceiling, and walls.  Depending on your expected spaces, you could consider a room scan complete when it has a totalArea above a certain value and has detected four walls, the floor, and the ceiling.

Even with these labels to help, the decision on when to consider a room 'complete' would be fairly arbitrary and not work in architecturally weird or connected spaces, so I wouldn't rely on this approach as a hard limit preventing users from uploading a space even if it doesn't meet the Spatial Understanding requirements you choose.
Giving the users a good UX for scanning is probably the best way to encourage them to scan everything, with overlaid information showing the detected walls/floor planes to help them know what hasn't been detected yet.

Comment: (This is assuming you're capturing image information at the same time as scanning your mesh.)